# Supposedly unchecked casts and rawtypes in Java are avoidable, so how do i get rid of the compiler warning when referencing nested generics?

Tags: java, generics, compiler-warnings

I have the following class (Java v8) , which I cannot get to compile without a warning. At the bottom you will see a static method that attempts to instantiate this class with a reference to HashSet.class. I can't figure out how to remove the warning from that method.

I understand the warning doesnt keep it from functioning, but this is a more of an academic question. Everything I've read says that rawtypes and unchecked casts were included for backwards compatibility, so how am I supposed to accomplish *properly* ? i.e. without suppressing or ignoring.

Edit: Upon compiling it directly, it now appears that the code won't even compile due to the below error, even though the IDE (Eclipse) reports no compiler errors, the build tool (maven) dies on compilation.

`incompatible types: java.lang.Class<java.util.HashSet> cannot be converted to java.lang.Class<? extends java.util.Set<T>>`

```
    public class RecollectConverter<C extends Collection<E>,E> implements Converter<C,C> {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -9040417792226361429L;

Class<? extends C> classs;

public RecollectConverter(Class<? extends C> c) {
    this.classs = c;
}

@Override
public Result<C> convertToModel(C value, ValueContext context) {
    try {
        C newin = classs.newInstance();
        newin.addAll(value);
        return Result.ok(newin);
    } 
    catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
    } 
}

@Override
public C convertToPresentation(C value, ValueContext context) {
    return value;
}

public static <T> RecollectConverter<Set<T>,T> forSet(){

    //wont compile, cannot convert
    //Class<? extends Set<T>> cl = HashSet.class;
    //Class<? extends Set<?>> cl = HashSet.class;

    //unchecked cast warning
    Class<? extends Set<T>> cl = (Class<? extends Set<T>>) HashSet.class;
    return new RecollectConverter<Set<T>, T>(cl);

}
```

}

Comment: `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` at the top of your method should probably do it

Comment: Per my question, I'm not looking to suppress it, I'm looking to solve it.

Comment: Sorry, I just read "how do I get rid of". Doing `Class<? extends Set> cl = HashSet.class;` should work. The problem is that `HashSet.class` returns a `Class<HashSet>` instead of a `Class<HashSet<?>>`, I think

Comment: @user the line `Class<? extends Set> cl = HashSet.class;` produces a rawtypes warning, which is part of what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: You really can't avoid warnings here no matter what you do. Warnings aren't errors. If you know for sure that what you're doing is correct, then there's no need to waste your time satisfying the compiler to make a raw types warning go away

Comment: @user That's why it's more of an academic question. I already have the code working, I'm just interested in knowing the proper way. If it is legit impossible to accomplish this without compiler warnings then that is a valid answer, it just doesn't match what ive read about those warnings being "avoidable".

Comment: @User Actually I just ran a compilation, and the compile now refuses to compile it (even though the IDE shows no errors). See my edit for the error message.

Comment: Do you only get that with `? extends Set<T>` or also `? extends Set<?>`? It's a shame Java didn't have generics from the very start. Raw types have really complicated things

Comment: the proper way is: get rid of the wildcard. <? extends Set> isn't necessary.

Comment: `Class<? extends Set<?>>` doesn't match the constructor, which needs a Class of type C (`C extends Collection<E>`) so the method won't compile.

Comment: @NathanHughes And replace it with what? just Set? Or just "?"

Comment: If you just have a `Class cl`, then that raw type will just work without you casting it. It'll still give a warning, of course

Comment: just Set should be fine.

Comment: @NathanHughes Set<?> is a rawtype, which produces yet another compiler warning, which is what I'm trying to avoid in the first place.

Comment: Sorry meant Set<T>